# Echo associated row value

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables

I have a form which is capturing input values as session params. One input in particular is a select with 5 different options ( cell phone carriers). I want the form to submit the id (carrier_id) but echo out the associated value (carrier_name) on a confirmation page.

Something like this:

```
<form action="confirm_form.php" role="form"> 
<div class="form-group">
<label for="carrier>Select Carrier</label>
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="carrier" value="">
    <?php 
         $q = "SELECT * FROM carriers";
         $carriers = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($carriers)) {
$carrier_id = $row['car_id'];
$carrier_name = $row['car_name'];

 echo "<option value='$carrier_id'>$carrier_name</option>";
 }
 ?>
</select>
</div>
<button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Add customer</button>
</form>


$carrier = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['carrier']);
```

The confirm_form.php page should echo out the carrier name but when i tried it either outputs the carrier_id or blank. Please help.

Im also assuming other factors in this quick overview which i didnt type out. ( i already have session_start(); called, for one)

Comment: Set this line inside while loop `echo "<option value='$carrier_id'>$carrier_name</option>";`

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing that typo out. However that was not the reason it would not output properly. I updated my code.

Comment: Why you want to use session? You can get value from $_POST.

Comment: Its part of another form so i thought it would be simpler to use a session. The form has mutiple parts. It is too late now to change it. The form does submit properly, just fyi.

Comment: Check my answer....

Answer (score 0):

**Main form and Set method post**

```
<form action="confirm_form.php" role="form" method="POST"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="carrier">Select Carrier</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="carrier" name="carrier">
        <?php 
          $q = "SELECT * FROM carriers";
          $carriers = mysqli_query($con, $q);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($carriers)){
            $carrier_id = $row['car_id'];
            $carrier_name = $row['car_name'];
            echo "<option value='$carrier_id'>$carrier_name</option>";
          }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Add customer</button>
</form>
```

**confirm_form.php**

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['carrier'])){
    $_SESSION['carrier']=$_POST['carrier'];
    $carrier = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['carrier']);

    //Then query here.........

   echo $_SESSION['carrier'];
  }

?>
```